# Objective-C - how to find objects with prop equal to date?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, filtering, nspredicate

I'm trying to filter an array of objects selecting those where a property of type NSDate are equal to a specific date. However, I only want to compare the date and ignore any time difference.

So I'm using an NSPredicate as so:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"PropertyWithDate == %@", 
                      [NSDate date]];
```

As both the object is storing the date with time and the value for now I am passing holds both. How do I arrange it to ignore the time part in both during the comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, an NSDate expresses a point in time, independent of timezones, so it only makes sense to talk about the date part of an NSDate with respect to a specific calendar and timezone.

The short answer is that you'll need to construct two NSDates: one for 12am the day of your date, and one for 12am the day after, and then set up your predicate to look for dates between the two:

```
NSPredicate *firstPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"PropertyWithDate > %@", firstDate];
NSPredicate *secondPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"PropertyWithDate < %@", secondDate];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubPredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstPredicate, secondPredicate, nil]];
```

To construct `firstDate` and `secondDate`, you'll want to use `NSCalendar`'s `components:fromDate:` and `dateFromComponents:` methods. If you want to use the device's current default calendar and timezone, you can just use `[NSCalendar calendar]` to get a calendar to use.

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSDatecomponents to do the compare.  There is a great video about date math and the libraries in the WWDC 2011 videos.

See the [NSDateComponents class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks Josh - your answer was also very useful but Yuji managed to pip you to the post.